# Upgraded EF 6 - The expression, is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, migration

I'm a bit new on EF and recently upgraded a Net Core 2.2 Project to NET 6. As expected a lot have broken on the EF side. I cant get my head around on this, working example on 2.2:

```
db.Feeds
.Include(t => t.FeedItem)
.Include(t => t.FeedItem).ThenInclude(t => (t as ContentFeedItem).CreatedByUser)
.ThenInclude(x => x.UserRoles).ThenInclude(x => x.Role)
```

It seems I cant no longer do the cast inside the ThenInclude, I get the following error:

> The expression '(t As ContentFeedItem).CreatedByUser' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations. For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.

**Feed Entity:**

```
public abstract class Feed
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int FeedItemId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("FeedItemId")] public FeedItem FeedItem { get; set; }

        //add source?
    }

    public class ChainFeed : Feed
    {
        public int ChainId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ChainId")] public Chain Chain { get; set; }
    }
    public class RestaurantFeed : ChainFeed
    {
        public int RestaurantId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("RestaurantId")] public Restaurant Restaurant { get; set; }
    }
    public class UserFeed : RestaurantFeed
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UserId")] public User User { get; set; }
    }
```

**ContentFeedItem Entity**

```
public abstract class ContentFeedItem : FeedItem
    {
        public int CreatedByUserId { get; set; } //who did this
        [ForeignKey("CreatedByUserId")] public User CreatedByUser { get; set; }
    }
```

Would love any help :) Thanks!
Complete Query if needed:

```
db.Feeds
.Include(t => t.FeedItem)
.Include(t => t.FeedItem).ThenInclude(t => (t as ContentFeedItem).CreatedByUser)
.ThenInclude(x => x.UserRoles).ThenInclude(x => x.Role)

.Include(t => t.FeedItem)
.ThenInclude(t => (t as MenuItemFeedItem).MenuItem)
.ThenInclude(t => t.Images)
.Include(t => t.FeedItem).ThenInclude(t => (t as MenuItemFeedItem).MenuItem)
.ThenInclude(t => t.MenuCategory)
.ThenInclude(t => t.Permissions)
.Include(t => t.FeedItem).ThenInclude(t => (t as MenuItemFeedItem).MenuItem)
.ThenInclude(t => t.MenuCategory)
.ThenInclude(t => t.MenuCategoryRestaurants)

.Include(t => t.FeedItem)
.ThenInclude(t => (t as WineItemFeedItem).AlcoholicItem)
.ThenInclude(t => t.MediaFiles)
.Include(t => t.FeedItem).ThenInclude(t => (t as WineItemFeedItem).AlcoholicItem)
.ThenInclude(t => t.Restaurants)
.Include(t => t.FeedItem).ThenInclude(t => (t as WineItemFeedItem).AlcoholicItem)
.ThenInclude(t => t.WineCategory)
.ThenInclude(t => t.Permissions)
.Include(t => t.FeedItem).ThenInclude(t => (t as WineItemFeedItem).AlcoholicItem)
.ThenInclude(t => t.WineCategory)
.ThenInclude(t => t.WineCategoryRestaurants)

.Include(t => t.FeedItem).ThenInclude(t => (t as MenuCategoryFeedItem).MenuCategory)
.ThenInclude(t => t.Permissions)
.Include(t => t.FeedItem).ThenInclude(t => (t as MenuCategoryFeedItem).MenuCategory)
.ThenInclude(t => t.MenuCategoryRestaurants)

.Include(t => t.FeedItem).ThenInclude(t => (t as EtiquetteFeedItem).Etiquette)
.ThenInclude(t => t.MediaFiles).ThenInclude(x => x.Thumbnail)
.Include(t => t.FeedItem).ThenInclude(t => (t as EtiquetteFeedItem).Etiquette)
.ThenInclude(t => t.EtiquetteRestaurants)
.Include(t => t.FeedItem).ThenInclude(t => (t as EtiquetteFeedItem).Etiquette)
.ThenInclude(t => t.EtiquetteCategory)
.ThenInclude(t => t.Permissions)
.Include(t => t.FeedItem).ThenInclude(t => (t as EtiquetteFeedItem).Etiquette)
.ThenInclude(t => t.EtiquetteCategory)
.ThenInclude(t => t.RestaurantsEtiquetteCategories)
.Include(t => t.FeedItem).ThenInclude(t => (t as EtiquetteFeedItem).Etiquette)
.ThenInclude(t => t.DefaultEtiquetteGroup).ThenInclude(t => t.DefaultEtiquettes)
.Include(t => t.FeedItem).ThenInclude(t => (t as PersonnelFeedItem).User)
.ThenInclude(t => t.UserRoles).ThenInclude(t => t.Role)
.Include(t => t.FeedItem).ThenInclude(t => t.FeedItemReactions)
.Include(t => t.FeedItem).ThenInclude(t => t.FeedItemComments).ThenInclude(t => t.User)
.Include(t => t.FeedItem).ThenInclude(t => (t as MenuItemReminderFeedItem).MenuItem)
.ThenInclude(t => t.Images)
.Include(t => t.FeedItem).ThenInclude(t => (t as MenuItemReminderFeedItem).MenuItem)
.ThenInclude(t => t.MenuCategory).ThenInclude(t => t.Permissions)
.Include(t => t.FeedItem).ThenInclude(t => (t as MenuItemReminderFeedItem).MenuItem)
.ThenInclude(t => t.MenuItemRestaurants)
.Include(t => t.FeedItem).ThenInclude(t => (t as MenuItemReminderFeedItem).MenuItem)
.ThenInclude(t => t.MenuCategory).ThenInclude(t => t.MenuCategoryRestaurants)
.Include(t => t.FeedItem).ThenInclude(t => (t as EtiquetteReminderFeedItem).Etiquette)
.ThenInclude(t => t.MediaFiles).ThenInclude(x => x.Thumbnail)
.Include(t => t.FeedItem).ThenInclude(t => (t as EtiquetteReminderFeedItem).Etiquette)
.ThenInclude(t => t.EtiquetteCategory).ThenInclude(t => t.Permissions)
.Include(t => t.FeedItem).ThenInclude(t => (t as EtiquetteReminderFeedItem).Etiquette)
.ThenInclude(t => t.EtiquetteRestaurants)
.Include(t => t.FeedItem).ThenInclude(t => (t as EtiquetteReminderFeedItem).Etiquette)
.ThenInclude(t => t.DefaultEtiquetteGroup).ThenInclude(t => t.DefaultEtiquettes)
.Include(t => t.FeedItem).ThenInclude(t => (t as QuizFinishedFeedItem).MenuCategory)
.Include(t => t.FeedItem).ThenInclude(t => (t as QuizFinishedFeedItem).CustomCategory)
.Include(t => t.FeedItem).ThenInclude(t => (t as QuizFinishedFeedItem).StandartCategory)
.Include(t => t.FeedItem).ThenInclude(t => (t as QuizFinishedFeedItem).Certification)

.Include(t => t.FeedItem).ThenInclude(t => (t as MenuItemFeedItem).MenuItem)
.ThenInclude(x => x.FeedComments)
.Include(t => t.FeedItem).ThenInclude(t => (t as MenuItemFeedItem).MenuItem)
.ThenInclude(x => x.FeedItemReactions)
.Include(t => t.FeedItem).ThenInclude(t => (t as WineItemFeedItem).AlcoholicItem)
.ThenInclude(x => x.FeedComments)
.Include(t => t.FeedItem).ThenInclude(t => (t as WineItemFeedItem).AlcoholicItem)
.ThenInclude(x => x.FeedItemReactions)
.Include(t => t.FeedItem).ThenInclude(t => (t as MenuItemReminderFeedItem).MenuItem)
.ThenInclude(x => x.FeedComments)
.Include(t => t.FeedItem).ThenInclude(t => (t as MenuItemReminderFeedItem).MenuItem)
.ThenInclude(x => x.FeedItemReactions);
```

Comment: Is that the entire query? (Or has the Select/Where been skipped for brevity in the context of the question?)

Comment: It was skipped, I added a complete example  and complete query too :)

Comment: @StevePy How is that in any way pertinent to the question?